# undefined method 'load_defaults' with Rails Generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm really new to Ruby and its Rails framework and I was following a tutorial when I ran into some issues using the rails generate command. I tried using rails generate scaffold and rails generate controller but it didn't work. The full trace is this:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:95:in `method_missing': undefined method `load_defaults' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x000055cdba53c180> (NoMethodError)
    from /home/eric/Projects/blog/config/application.rb:12:in `<class:Application>'
    from /home/eric/Projects/blog/config/application.rb:10:in `<module:Blog>'
    from /home/eric/Projects/blog/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:92:in `preload'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:153:in `serve'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:141:in `block in run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `loop'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application.rb:135:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I think that the main issue is that I'm missing the 'load_defaults' method, but I couldn't find anything on how to resolve the issue. For context, I'm doing this all on a completely new rails project on Ubuntu - the only things I've done so far are rails new and bundle install.

Somewhat curiously, this issue is only popping up on new rails projects that I've created. I tried using rails generate commands on a project I had earlier and it worked. I couldn't figure out what was different between the projects though.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you try `spring stop` and then try the generator again?

Comment: Yep! I also tried updating rails, ruby, and railstie!